# Bootstrap modal not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Im trying to create a modal using the bootstrap code and for some reason it is not working for me. I even tried to just create a new html file and put the code there and linked it to a css file with the css code from bootstrap but it doesn't work there too. Im using the following code in the actual file -

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Launch Modal</a>
<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-header">
<button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
<h3>Modal header</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body…</p>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
</div>
</div>
```

It just adds this to the end of my url - #myModal

Can someone tell me what might be wrong with it or give me sample code for a modal

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please update your question to include the full HTML, so we can see if you're including the needed JavaScript.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/q6NJj/

Comment: There is no javascript in it because bootstrap says that this code can be used for a modal without javascript

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not loading bootstrap correctly

Here is a cdn from where you can load bootstrap ( add this to your `<head>` of your doc )

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added this to the <head> but nothing changed

Comment: ok try to press f12 in your browser, go to your console refresh the page , look at the console and see if any errors show up there